# Neo4j query to return a collection of collections

Tags: java, collections, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I can write a query that displays a graph of multiple nodes pointing to other nodes. I want to get that in my Java program as a collection of collections.

```
MATCH (o) -[r]-> (s) -[l*]-> (b)  WHERE ... return DISTINCT(b)
```

In neo4j web query it displays 5 sets of (b) nodes each with a single relationship to another (b) node. So 10 (b) nodes in total. I want a collection of size 5 with each item being a collection of 2 nodes.

Make sense?

My java interface:

```
@Query("start s=node({0}) MATCH (o)-[r]-(s)-[l*]->(b:Thing) return DISTINCT(b)")
public Collection<Collection<Thing>> findThings(Thing thing);
```

Like this I get a collection of size 10 of collections of size 1 - each node by itself in each collection. If my return type is Collection<Thing> then I get all 10 nodes. I want one collection with 5 collections of 2 Things.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to return:

```
MATCH (o) -[r]-> (s) -[l*]-> (b)  WHERE ... return collect( DISTINCT b))
```

**But your query should be more specific and using labels!**

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting RestNodes and I don't think we are storing any nodes by that type. My actual query is more specific w/ appropriate labels. But I must be doing something else wrong. I doubt the community could help more w/o seeing the data structure stored and actual query. I'll try working at it w/ my coworkers today. Thx

Comment: Even with RestNodes it should be able to map them. Otherwise you can always try to use a @QueryResult for the mapping. Or actually you can just `return DISTINCT b` and use a `Collection<Thing>` that would be the correct thing to do.